# Como armazenar respostas dos meus scanf/gets em C

Tags: c, string, struct, scanf

Preciso realizar esse sistema para faculdade, sendo essas  funcionalidades essenciais:
O sistema deverá oferecer, ao usuário, as seguintes funcionalidades:

- Listar os veículos cadastrados;
- Inserir um novo veículo;
- Listar os veículos filtrando-se por ano de fabricação;
- Listar os veículos com o ano de fabricação acima de um certo valor especificado pelo usuário.
- Listar os veículos filtrando-se pelo modelo.

O sistema deverá armazenar os veículos ordenados pelo ano de fabricação, ou seja, ao inserir um novo veículo, este deve ser inserido em ordem crescente de ano de fabricação.

O que não consigo fazer é salvar as respostas de cadastro do veículo, por exemplo, o usuário vai realizar um cadastro de um carro, não consigo saber onde e como salvar e como resgatar as respostas em forma de lista. Outra coisa que não consigo é limitar as respostas em 10 veículos no máximo.

Segue o código fonte abaixo:

```
struct cadastro{
        char marca[30];
        char modelo[30];
        char placa [9];
    } veiculos [10];

int main(void) {
    
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    int digitado;
    int valor;
    
     
    printf("O que deseja realizar?: ");
    printf("\nDigite 1 para Listar os Veículos já cadastrados\nDigite 2 inserir um novo veículo\nDigite 3 para ver os anos de fabricação dos veículos cadastrados\nDigite 4 para ver um veículo do preço que desejar\nDigite 5 para ver os modelos dos veículos.\n\n");
    scanf("%d", &digitado);
    
    if(digitado == 2){  
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<1;i++){
        printf("\nDigite a marca do carro: \n\n");
        scanf("%s", &veiculos[i].marca);
        setbuf(stdin,NULL);
        printf("\nDigite o modelo e ano do carro: \n\n");
        gets(veiculos[i].modelo);
        setbuf(stdin,NULL);
        printf("\nDigite a placa do carro(Ex: ABC-0123): \n\n");
        scanf("%s", &veiculos[i].placa);
        setbuf(stdin,NULL);
        getchar();
        
    }
    for(i=0;i<1;i++){
        printf("\nCarro da marca: %s, do modelo/ano: %s, com a placa: %s adicionado à lista!\n",veiculos[i].marca,veiculos[i].modelo,veiculos[i].placa);
    }
}else if(digitado == 1){
        printf("\nCarro da marca: %s, do modelo/ano: %s, com a placa: %s",veiculos[0].marca,veiculos[0].modelo,veiculos[0].placa);
}else if(digitado == 3){
    printf("Anos dos veículos listados: %i", veiculos[0].modelo);
}else if(digitado == 5){
    printf("Aqui estão os modelos dos carros: %s", veiculos[0].modelo);
}else if(digitado == 4){
    printf("Digite um valor: ");
    scanf("%d", &valor);
    if(valor < 10000){
        printf("Ano: %d", veiculos[0].modelo<2010);
    }else{
        printf("Ano: %d", veiculos[0].modelo>2010);
        setbuf(stdin,NULL);
    }
}
    
    
system('pause');
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seu programa tem um certo número de problemas, todos problemas comuns. E assim pode ser útil para mais usuários ter uma resposta aqui

> Como armazenar respostas dos meus scanf/gets em C

Acho que não era isso que você queria perguntar. De todo modo: não use `gets()`, essa função foi abolida há décadas. Use `fgets()`.

Para armazenar os resultados o primeiro argumento é um ponteiro para a área que vai receber os resultados.

`scanf()` não aloca memória, então para cada especificador, aquelas coisas que começam por `%` no primeiro argumento, você deve passar um endereço.

Teste sempre o retorno dessas funções. SEMPRE.

Não vou corrigir o programa todo porque nem ajuda muito. Mas vou listar alguns dos problemas e você poderá ir acertando se achar adequado

```
            gets(veiculos[i].modelo);
```

Pode ser algo como

```
            fgets(&veiculos[i].modelo, sizeof veiculos[i].modelo, stdin);
```

#### o retorno de `fgets()`

`fgets()` tem esse parâmetro que limita o tamanho do campo. A falta disso em `gets()` foi uma bobagem dos anos 70 e deixa uma abertura para um estouro do campo. Por isso é um desastre em termos de segurança e estabilidade do programa, e a função foi abandonada.

Mas `fgets()` retorna um ponteiro para o valor lido, assim como `gets()`. E você tem que testar.

Eis o que acontece: se não ler nada a função retorna `NULL` e os dados no primeiro argumento não são alterados. Isso quer dizer que o programa vai achar que leu os mesmos dados que já estavam lá, se é que tinha algum.

#### o retorno de `scanf()`

```
                scanf("%d %d %d", &digitado, &outro, &mais_um);
```

Essa chamada por exemplo lê 3 valores. Então pode retornar 3, 2, 1, 0 ou -1 conforme leia algo. -1 para erro.

Se você não testar nunca vai saber o que leu e se leu. Se o cara teclar `w` ao invés de `2` que é pertinho no teclado, vai retornar zero...

Mas se ele teclar `2 2 w` vai retornar `2`. Ou se ele digitar `2 w` vai retornar... `1`. Acho que entendeu.

#### Escreva em torno dos dados

```
struct cadastro
{
    char marca[30];
    char modelo[30];
    char placa[9];
} veiculos[10];
```

Essa é sua única estrutura. E é global. Está declarada fora de `main()` ou de qualquer função do programa. Isso é um desastre, proibido em toda parte, escolas e empresas.

E de todo modo entenda que isso não é um cadastro. A `struct` descreve apenas um carro. O cadastro seria uma coleção de carros. Com um certo número. De carros.

Compare com essa estrutura, comum em C

```
typedef struct
{
    char marca[30];
    char modelo[30];
    char placa[9];

} Carro;

typedef struct 
{
    unsigned n; // quantos carros
    Carro    c[10];

}   Cadastro;

int main(void)
{
    Cadastro cad1;
    Cadastro outro;
```

E veja que ao usar `Cadastro` como uma `struct` que tem um contador e um vetor para até 10 `Carro` seu programa fica muito mais simples. Cada cadastro tem seu contador dentro. Isso é encapsulamento, uma daquelas palavras chiques de programação orientação a objetos.

Não use `system()` nunca. Para nada. Está programando em C. system() foi escrita em C, o Windows foi escrito em C, a API do Windows é C. Pode fazer tudo.

Não use `setbuf()` Não vai funcionar como quer. Esqueça isso de buffer de teclado e `lixo`. Não existe `lixo de teclado`, apenas programas que não consomem os dados direito.

Não use `getchar()` para parar o programa sem uma mensagem avisando do que está fazendo.

```
        for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
```

Exceto nos óbvios casos em que a lógica exija declare as variáveis de controle do loop dentro do comando. Isso é um pesadelo de manutenção e sempre vai cair na sua cabeça. Em algum lugar vai ter uma variável global à função com o ingênuo nominho de `i`.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
```

E sobre isso... Qual a razão de um loop que roda uma única vez, de 0 até 0?